# Google scripts timestamp not updating onEdit when data sent from Active Campaign automation

Tags: google-apps-script, timestamp

I've set up a trigger for Active Campaign opt-ins to dump into sheets (for a Data Studio report I share) but the Active Campaign integration doesn't deliver a timestamp, so I've set up the following apps script to populate a timestamp using onEdit in the second column when this happens. however, it isn't auto-populating. It does work if I physically type something in to the first column but not when the live data comes through. I'm a bit of a newb, so not sure what I am missing:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveCell();
   if (r.getColumn() < 2 && ss.getName()=='Update opt ins') { // 2. If Edit is done in any column before Column (B)  And sheet name is Sheet1 then:
var celladdress ='B'+ r.getRowIndex() 
    ss.getRange(celladdress).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

#### This works

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
   if (e.range.columnStart < 2 && sh.getName()=='Set Sheet Name') { 
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm");
  }
}
```

You do not need to create an installable trigger as this is a simple trigger.

Comment: Thanks Cooper - I'm still not getting any success. Does it matter that there are two worksheets in the one spreadsheet?

Comment: Did you set the sheet name?  You should be editing column1 and getting a date in column2.  I just tested it and it works

Comment: Yes definitely set the sheet name. And when I edit in it myself it works, but not when the data populates from the automation (same as before). Very strange

Comment: That's the expected behavior of an onEdit trigger.  It only fires for user edits

Comment: OK what trigger can we use for cells that are auto-populated via an API etc?

Comment: Possibly onChange() with changeType  equal to other. I know it works for imports