# Copy Row Contents but Only Certain Cells and add Timestamp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to have it that when a row is edited that it only copies the name phone and adds a timestamp of the edit on another tab in Google Sheets.

```
function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Main');
  var date  = new Date();
  var rowIdx = sheet.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
  var rowValues = sheet.getRange(rowIdx,1,1,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  Logger.log(rowValues);
  var destValues = [];
  destValues.push(rowValues[0][0]);// copy data from col A to col A
  destValues.push(rowValues[0][2]);// copy data from col C to col B
  destValues.push(rowValues[0][1]);// copy data from col B to col C
  destValues.push(rowValues[0][3]);// copy data from col D to col D

  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Updates');
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,destValues.length).setValues([destValues]);



}
```

The above is working but i cannot figure out how to get the timestamp to show.

The outcome should display the roadname, phone and then C:C should have timestamp of change made.

I have updated the below sheet to show expected outcome

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V3Ne9L0kB97OkFKwlidx40yN__sx78aRik_Ujiej2Wc/edit#gid=1523701088

How I want it to look.
[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWUpT.png)

Data source
[Source Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC8sZ.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Thanks for including your script and your spreadsheet, but your question needs to stand on its own, so... you should explain what it is exactly that your scenario is trying to achieve, you shouldn't expect that a user must look at your spreadsheet to understand your data, and you should include an example of how a successful result would appear. On a tangent, you have defined a timestamp (`var date  = new Date();`), but if you're wondering why it isn't showing, it's probably because you never write the value to a cell (whether by adding to the array, or a separate `setValue`).

Comment: Related question: [Google scripts timestamp not updating onEdit when data sent from Active Campaign automation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72481258/1330560)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your written explanation is inconsistent with your sample output which is inconsistent with your script. `destValues.push()`-you are pushing 4 (four) values onto the array (including "Phone Number",  "Date Contacted" and "Clan Name") but your expected outcome only has three columns (excluding "Date Contacted" and "Phone number"), but the "Phone number" is in the "Clan Name" column.

---

**REPLACE**

```
  destValues.push(rowValues[0][0]);// copy data from col A to col A
  destValues.push(rowValues[0][2]);// copy data from col C to col B
  destValues.push(rowValues[0][1]);// copy data from col B to col C
  destValues.push(rowValues[0][3]);// copy data from col D to col D
  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Updates');
  dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,destValues.length).setValues([destValues]);
```

---

**WITH**

```
var date  = new Date()
destValues.push(rowValues[0][0]);// copy data from col A to col A
destValues.push(rowValues[0][2]);// copy data from col C to col B
destValues.push(date);// copy data from col B to col C
var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Updates');
dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1,1,destValues.length).setValues([destValues]);
```